# Is it right to import variables from __init__ into a unit-test script?

Tags: python, unit-testing, conventions

Let's say that we have a directory with the following structure:

```
tests/
|-- __init__.py
|-- test_foo.py
```

where package `foo` is tested. In `test_foo.py`, variable `bar` is defined (and modified) to later be used.

Now imagine that instead of one file, we have around 20 `test_fooX.py`, where `bar` is initialized in every test.

Is it good practice to initiate `bar` in `__init__.py` and import it directly in every test? E.g.

```
from __init__ import bar
```

The Zen of python mentions that:

*Explicit is better than implicit.*

Defining `bar` in every single script would be what the explicit way. However, importing variables improves the structure of the tests/project.

A real scenario would be a logger (imported from `foo`), whose logging level needs to be changed; or the location of a specific directory instead of defining it every time.

Comment: You should use `from . import bar` instead of `from __init__ ...`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really implicit about `__init__.py`. A package is a module. Because  a package is *implemented* by a directory containing a file named `__init__.py`, that file contains the contents of the module `tests`, with other files implementing submodules belonging to the same package.